# Android Room Caching with Single Entity and JSON values

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

We are trying to implement a room caching mechanism with both an in-memory cache and a disk cache which contains only a single entity which has a unique key per network call and the result stored  in json. Here is the DAO and the Entity,

```
    @Dao
    interface CacheDao {
        @Query("SELECT * FROM cache WHERE key = :key LIMIT 1")
        fun getOneByKey(key: String): LiveData<Cache>
    }
```

```
    @Entity(tableName = "cache")
    data class Cache (
        @ColumnInfo(name = "cache_key")
        val key: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "response")
        val response: String,
    )
```

Depending on where we retrieve the data, we parse the json to the relevant model.

However when trying to use a repository pattern and MVVM, we have a viewmodel getting data from the repository, the repository has a function which makes a network call and caches the data or hust returns the data from the cache. Livedata is used and the Viewmodel is observing the livedata. The thing is, The DAO returns LiveData, while the repository must return, say: LiveData. How can I implement the this conversion in the repository? Do I have to have a seperate observer on the repository which observes the DAO and once a change occurs the repository convert the LiveData data from the database to LiveData? if so how to create the new observer on the repository? In particular what context to use? And will the viewmodel still be observing the repository for changes? I am quite new with Room, so might be missing something quite obvious. I've searched the internet for a solution but couldn't find anything similar to this particular scenario. Would be glad if you could provide any suggestions about how I should proceed.

Thanks in advance.